# Dumping W32pServiceTable

Tags: windows, kernel, windbg

I want to see what function in win32k.sys driver handles specific syscall number. 
I attach windbg to GUI process since win32k.sys is season space driver. 
Then I shift first DWORD value right by 4 bits add base address of W32pServiceTable and use u command to show function in WinDbg but address isn't valid. I checked KiSystemCall64 and it seems to be doing the same thing.

```
!process 0 0 winlogon.exe
.process /p (PROCESS addr)
.reload
```

[image: dd win32k!W32pServiceTable - screenshot]
Answer: DWORD value from table is loaded with this instruction

```
movsxd  r11,dword ptr [r10+rax*4]
```

W32pServiceTable DWORD values has bit at 31 position set to 1 so movsxd sets upper 32 bits of r11 register to 1 then adding r11 and table base address leads to correct function.

Comment: The pointers in the service tables (kernel and win32k) are now (since Windows 10) encoded; [see this page](https://ired.team/miscellaneous-reversing-forensics/windows-kernel/glimpse-into-ssdt-in-windows-x64-kernel) for further explanations.

Comment: Shifting value by 4 bits isn't encoding these 4 bits are used for something else. I can get functions addresses from KiServiceTable just fine

Answer (score 0):

These values are negative so you need to preserve that when you shift off the bits. For example:

```
0: kd> dd win32k!W32pServiceTable L1
fffff88b`d1568000  ff8c8340
0: kd> u win32k!W32pServiceTable + ffffffff`fff8c834 L1
win32k!NtUserGetThreadState:
fffff88b`d14f4834 4883ec28        sub     rsp,28h
```

Also, WinDbg is very picky/weird/broken/unpredictable when it comes to sign extension so you need to be careful about how you do this. For example, this doesn't work:

```
0: kd> u win32k!W32pServiceTable + fff8c834 L1
fffff88c`d14f4834 ??              ???
```

Due to WinDbg zero extending the value. But this does:

```
0: kd> u win32k!W32pServiceTable + (fff8c834) L1
win32k!NtUserGetThreadState:
fffff88b`d14f4834 4883ec28        sub     rsp,28h
```

Because the () causes WinDbg to sign extend instead of zero extend.

Lastly, this happens even on the normal service table, it's not just a Win32k thing.